# Disable Windows 10 system popups (Restart, Update, Low Power)

Tags: windows, notifications, popup, windows-10, windows-update

My global problem is to switch off all the...

- notifications
- popups by Windows
- system hard errors dialogs

...while some application is running.

Switching off Notificatins and Errors dialogs via Registry was an easy task - thanks for Google and MSDN.

And working with popups (as on the picture - link below) is a hard task. I couldn't find any detailed description about their behaviour and how to control them.

1. Does anybody know how to switch off all the similar popups (not only regarding updates)?
2. And which types of these popups are there in Windows? I saw about Restaring, Updates ready, Low Battery...but I suppose that there are more.
3. And the last: how to emulate these popups for testing purposes?

Example of popup:

[image: example of popup]

Answer (score 1):

Set all values to 0 for the following registry -

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings

[RegEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTC0j.png)

Comment: Thank you anyway, but I asked certainly about popups as in attached picture :(